# Create array with different sizes of array in C++

Tags: c++11

One can generate list with different length of list in python :

```py
layers = 3
lst = []
for i in range(1, layers+2):
    lst.append([0]*i)
```

Above code generates 2d list:

```
[[0],
 [0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So how can I create a 2d array like the 2d list above in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: This is straight-forward by nesting `std::vector`, i.e. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. Have you tried that and if so, what issues came up?

Comment: I'm new to C++ so I'm not really familiar with the datatypes. However, after reading some articles about vector, the problem was solved. Thanks a lot !